# How to retrieve Json data with vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js

I try to retrieve data from json api with vue.js 2 with this code.

```
var mnlink = new Vue({
    el: '#mnlink',
    data:{
        mnlinks: null
    },
    created: function () {
        fetch("/api/v1/getmenulink/apikey/123456789")
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(mnlinks => {
                this.mnlinks=mnlinks;
            });
    }

});
```

my component.

```
Vue.component('vx-menulink', {
template: `<li class="media notification-message dark-f"><a class="withripple" :href="(url)" :target="(target)">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="material-icons">{{icon}}</i></span>
                            <span class="ml-lg">{{name}}</span><div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
                    </li>`,
props: {
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    icon: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    target: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
} });
```

and its work like a charm, but i have a problem with owl-carousel. i cant call my component with owl-carousel. so i try to use another trick like this below. my problem is, how to convert my json api to Array.apply?

```
var list = Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).fill(
    {
    id: "1",
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'mail@example.com',
    phone: '123456789'
});
console.time('test')

const vm = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        foo: list
    }
});
```

Thank's for any replies.

Comment: `Array.apply` just creates an array.  You probably already have an array.

Comment: @SLaks can you explain with my code? i want to change this {
    id: "1",
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'mail@example.com',
    phone: '123456789'
} with my restapi. can you help me ?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of JSON and arrays.

Comment: so I ask what makes me confused. because i am learning about json. I'm newbie. thanks for ur reply.

Comment: Start by learning the basics of Javascript objects & arrays.